# SSIS Script Task reference dll programmatically

Tags: dll, ssis, external, gac

I have built software that is capable of exporting DTSX package automatically. This package among other objects has also a ScriptTask (C#). All are compiled and run just fine.

Now the new requirement is to call a class in that ScriptTask, which exists inside an external DLL we have built, so other applications can consume the same code. We did our homework, and we included this DLL into the GAC successfully during the installation of the software.

The problem is that "using our library" is still not recognized in the script.

While searching a little bit, we figured out, that we need to reference this DLL also inside the References folder. This we can do it of course via DataTools / VisualStudio UI.

The issue is that we need to do that programmatically:

We have this piece of code that generates the Project

```
task.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.LoadNewProject(task.ProjectTemplatePath, null, "MyScriptProject");
```

And also, we have this piece of code that creates the MainScript

```
task.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.AddFileToProject(ScriptName + ".cs", MainScript.ToString());
```

I am unable to figure out how I can include the reference DLL programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You can programmatically update the script task by replacing the appropriate XML node in the the DTSX file

The node path depends on where the script task has been created within the SSIS package, in my case the node path was

`/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable/DTS:ObjectData/pipeline/components/component[@refId="Package\Data Flow Task\Script Component"]/properties`

The @refId you will be looking for will start with Package \ Dataflow name \ Component name

[image]

This node will have sub nodes which contains the C# scripts as well as the binary that was built off this script

The property name "SourceCode" contains the C# scipts in an array called arrayElements, the array will have three sub nodes for each file, these subnodes are called arrayElement, first value is the relative path and name, second is file encoding and third is the file content

[image: SourceCodeNode]

The property name "BinaryCode" contains the .dll that was build from the scripts, it also contains an arrayElement array with two entries, first the dll name and the second the base64 encoded dll binary

[image: BinaryCodeNode]

To get the data to populate these items you will need to create a template of the C# build directory, apply your changes, build the code and take the resulting files and replace them on their appropriate nodes

To create the template open the script via SSIS task,

1. Click on the project in solution explorer to and go file save VstaProject.sln
   [image: SaveSLN]
2. Go to the saved folder, you get the folder off the solutions properties dialog
   [image: FindTheFolder]
3. Copy this folder somewhere so that you can reuse it to build your custom stuff
4. Modify the .cs files in your template directory and add your custom reference dll's to your .csproj file
5. Call MSBUILD in the same directory as your .csproj to output the dll, its important that you use the VS MSBUILD, VS2017 you can find it in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe`

6. Take these files and package them into a XML node in the DTSX file

**Initial Answer**

Microsoft provides a workaround for loading DLL's that aren't in the GAC

[Load assembly that isnt in the GAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac)

Please see below extract from a SSIS script, I loaded the JSON dll's from the nuget install directory. This DLL is not in the GAC

```c#
static ScriptMain()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
}
static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name.Contains("Newtonsoft.Json"))
    {
        string path = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\plugins\Diagnostics\";
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ockert Pretorius, I understand that you are using this code to load the DLL which is not in GAC, but still, you should reference the DLL in the references, right?

Comment: @StavrosKoureas , yes I missed that part of your question, you will still need create a reference to it from within the script task because the script task compiles the binary and saves it in the dtsx. You could possibly compile outside of ssis and store the result in the dtsx, or if the binary does not change you could compile it and just reuse it. The script code and binary gets stored as CDATA in the dtsx file in XML format

Comment: yes this is the key question, so, do you have any idea how we can add the reference programmatically?
or can you provide any info on how we can add the compiled library as CDATA into the DTSX definition programmatically?
(we built the package with EzAPI and with standard Microsoft DTS libraries)

Comment: Does the script task change? If the inputs and outputs stay the same you can transplant the CDATA into a new DTSX. If the Inputs and Outputs change you would need to recompile and replace the binary data, this should be possible but would be technically difficult

Comment: @StavrosKoureas I've updated my answer with how I would go about building a custom script task dll containing references

Comment: your answer seems a solution, and thank you. I followed let's say a more "elegant" solution to consume the dll from custom path using Reflection. Now I came up with a different problem. The user who is running the dtsx must be an administrator while executing from DataTools. The issue is that when it runs from the agent the user who is running the agent, should be an administrator. Now I am looking for the minimum rights of the user who is running the agent, giving permissions only to the directory without an administrator user, dtsx keeps failing with this scenario.

Comment: I just had a look at Reflection and it is definitely a better option, I'll keep that in mind next time I need to load dll's, unfortunately I'm not too familiar with firing dtsx from folders, I deploy my dtsx to a SSIS catalog and which gets fired by the database service account so I've not run into issues like that before